# Suma de matrices en haskell

Tags: recursión, matriz, haskell

Hola que tal ojala puedan ayudarme me esta marcando un error al compilar mi codigo este es mi codigo

```
numFilas :: Num a => Matriz a -> Int
numFilas = fst . snd . bounds

numColumnas:: Num a => Matriz a -> Int
numColumnas = snd . snd . bounds

dimension :: Num a => Matriz a -> (Int,Int)
dimension p = (numFilas p, numColumnas p)

sumaMatrices:: Num a => Matriz a -> Matriz a -> Matriz a
sumaMatrices p q = 
    array ((1,1),(m,n)) [((i,j),p!(i,j)+q!(i,j)) |i <- [1..m], j <- [1..n]]
    where (m,n) = dimension p
```

**Este es el error**

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[[Integer]]’ with ‘Array (Int, Int) a’
  Expected type: Matriz a
    Actual type: [[Integer]]
• In the first argument of ‘sumaMatrices’, namely
    ‘[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]’
  In the expression:
    sumaMatrices [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] [[4, 5, 6], [6, 5]]
  In an equation for ‘it’:
      it = sumaMatrices [[1, 2, ....], [4, 5]] [[4, 5, ....], [6, 5]]
• Relevant bindings include
    it :: Matriz a (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

:2:30: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘[[Integer]]’ with ‘Array (Int, Int) a’
Expected type: Matriz a
Actual type: [[Integer]]
• In the second argument of ‘sumaMatrices’, namely
‘[[4, 5, 6], [6, 5]]’
In the expression:
sumaMatrices [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] [[4, 5, 6], [6, 5]]
In an equation for ‘it’:
it = sumaMatrices [[1, 2, ....], [4, 5]] [[4, 5, ....], [6, 5]]
• Relevant bindings include
it :: Matriz a (bound at :2:1)

[image: Error en imagen]

Comment: Aunque intuyo cómo has definido el tipo `Matriz` y cómo invocas la función `sumaMatrices`, estaría bien que lo añadieras explícitamente al código. No has definido `Matriz` como lista de listas, por lo que estás invocando mal la función suma. Mírate esta web para ver ejemplos: https://www.glc.us.es/~jalonso/vestigium/matrices-en-haskell/

Comment: Si esta definida Matriz agrego mas tarde el codigo pero no se si  el error este en la forma de colocar la matriz